# Importrange from a source with a variable number of rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I am quite new to Googlescript so please excuse my easy question: I want to import data from one googlesheet to another one using `IMPORTRANGE()`. The source range from the source googlesheet can have 1 to 6 rows filled (variable) but my targetrange of my target googlesheet must have only the non empty rows.

```
var urlsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Enter Report URL');

// the URL of the source Googlesheet is pasted in cell A5 of the target Googlesheet:'Enter Report URL'

var cell20=urlsheet.getRange("A5");

var cellB20value=cell20.getValue();

// then I use the Importrange formula on the cell with the URL and paste it in cell A20 which gives me the importrange of the source sheet

var temptarget=urlsheet.getRange("A20");
    temptarget.setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE('+cellB20value+',"Admin Use Only!A4:U9")');

//Finally, I paste the Importrange from A20 in the last row of my target sheet:

var Creditdetail=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Credit_Detail');

var lastrowcredit= Creditdetail.getLastRow()+1;

var finaltarget=Creditdetail.getRange(lastrowcredit,1);

  temptarget.copyTo(finaltarget, {contentOnly:true});
```

But this keeps on adding the 6 rows I asked for (A4 to U9 in the source sheet)...

Can someone help me figure out how to Import only the Non empty rows ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just `var a = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Admin Use Only").getRange("A4:U9"); var b = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Credit_Detail'); b.getRange(b.getLastRow() +1, 1, a.length).setValues(a)`?

Comment: Please learn to edit your format, how you highlight your problem.

Comment: Hi @Altigraph thank you for your time. Your solution looks easy. But when I run the script on b.getRange(b.getLastRow() +1, 1, a.length).setValues(a) I get the error message:'Cannot find method getRange(number,number,(class))'

Comment: Please use backticks to indicate code formatting. The above code should be `var a = ... getRange("A4:U9").getValues();`, give that a try

Comment: Thanks again @Altigraph, Ill keep note about the backticks. What you suggested works... Now this still does not solve the problem as my two first rows from my source range (A4 to U5) are filled with values but my 4 last rows (A6 to U9) are filled with formulas but no values. I would like to retrieve only the cells from the rows having actual values ...

Comment: Use a for loop, `var validRows = [];` ... `if (a[i][0] !== '') { validRows.push(a[i]); }`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`IMPORTRANGE` will import all the values encompassed by the reference specified as its second argument.

There are basically two optional paths:

- Filter the data before importing it, i.e. by using `FILTER`, `QUERY`, etc. then use the reference of the range that holds the results or by using Google Apps Script to getValues / getDisplayValues and then filtering by using some JavaScript methods like `Array.prototype.filter(callback)`.
- Filter the data after it was imported, i.e. by using `QUERY` if this will be done on the same formula, `FILTER` if it will be done by using another formula.